# PHP Cut string to 5 words backwards and forward from highlighted keywords from array

Tags: php, string, format, highlight, cut

[I need to find in big strings each keyword, highlight them by  and leave only five words before and after this keyword. You can see in screenshot i created php script which](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwSaD.jpg)

Link to image that shows what i have and what i need:
http://dawid969.webd.pl/cut.jpg

Code i have - PHP - I created functionality to highlight each word but i cant cut the string (around highlighted words five words backwards and 5 words forward) there are so weird situations when each highlighted word are next to each other, then we cant cut string, we cut string only when different in words beetwen highlighted words is greater than 10 words.

Anyone have idea how can i make last point? - cutting string?

```
<?php
$sentence = "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again";

$arrayOfWords = array('explain', 'complete', 'pleasure');

echo "<b>Sentence:</b> ".$sentence;
echo '<br><br>';

echo "<b>Words to find (in array):</b> ";
print_r($arrayOfWords);

echo "<br><br>";

$look = explode(' ',$sentence);

foreach($look as $find){
    for($i=0;$i<count($arrayOfWords);$i++){
        $keyword = $arrayOfWords[$i];
        if(stripos($find, $keyword) !== false) {
            if(!isset($highlight)){ 
                $highlight[] = $find;
            } else { 
                if(!in_array($find,$highlight)){ 
                    $highlight[] = $find;
                } 
            }
        }   
    }
} 

if(isset($highlight)){ 
    foreach($highlight as $key => $replace){
        $sentence = str_replace($replace,'<b>'.$replace.'</b>',$sentence);
    } 
} 

echo "<b>Sentence formatted I have:</b> ".$sentence;

echo '<br><br>';

echo "<b>Sentence formated I need: </b> But I must <b>explain</b> to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing <b>pleasure</b> and praising pain was born and I will give you a <b>complete</b> account of the system, and expound... ...one rejects, dislikes, or avoids <b>pleasure</b> itself, because it is pleasure,... ...not know how to pursue <b>pleasure</b> rationally encounter consequences that are...";
?>
```

Comment: In your first link, why doesn't `explain` have the same "cut" logic applied to it?

Comment: Do you want to match `explaining`, `completeness` and `pleasures`?

Comment: Please confirm that this is your EXACT desired output from your input string:  `But I must <b>explain</b> to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing <b>pleasure</b> and praising pain was born... ...I will give you a <b>complete</b> account of the system, and... ...one rejects, dislikes, or avoids <b>pleasure</b> itself, because it is <b>pleasure</b>, but because those who do not know how to pursue <b>pleasure</b> rationally encounter consequences that are...`

Comment: @mickmackusa Ye this is what i looking for

Comment: What about extended words that I asked about?

Comment: I dont understand, Could you ask this same in other words or smth please

Comment: Where should the bold tags be if the string contains: `I love "explaining" things.`?  Inside the double quotes?  Outside the double quotes? End tag before `ing`?

Comment: It can be in "explain" but if its problem in this situation dont highlight this world "explaining"

Comment: Oh no, I am NOT looking for the easy way out.  I want to know the intention of your code.  I like a challenge.

Comment: Are the keywords supplied by users? or are the strings 100% trustworthy?  Might they contain non-letters?

Comment: To visualize that. User can search key words in text by writing in input on page. After confirm words by user i want to show him fragment of text but this text is very long sometimes and i want to show him only keywords and 5 words backwards and forwards this keyword

Comment: Supplied by users, yes it main contains no letters for example article code

Comment: Okay, if the keyword strings are DEFINITELY only letters, I am going to leave out "character escaping" in my solution.  Posting soon.

Comment: i mean someone can search in text "article 503"

Comment: Can they search `shut your ***`? or `Amen.` ?  My solution leverages regex, so these are important details to iron out.

Comment: Yes they can search for this

Comment: ...then I will need to update my answer. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My regex pattern may take a little "staring at" but basically they match upto 5 "words" (using term loosely) on either side of each found keyword.

The sentence is first divided into an array of substrings that either DO and DO NOT contain keywords.  Call `var_export($chunks);` to see what I mean.

Then each element is conditionally processed.  If the element:

- contains a keyword, the emboldening action is taken.
- is exactly one space, the element is left alone.
- does not contain a keyword and is the first or last element, it becomes `...`.
- does not contain a keyword and occurs mid-sentence, it becomes `... ...`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6694aa54f17af75e657432c8a213b14862972ef))

```
$sentence = "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again";
$arrayOfWords=['explain','complete','pleasure'];
$pattern_core=implode('|',array_map(function($v){return preg_quote($v,'/');},$arrayOfWords));  // escape regex-impacting characters and pipe together

// split the sentence on keywords with upto 5 "words" padding, retain the delimiters
$chunks=preg_split("/((?:\S+\s+){0,5}\S*(?:".$pattern_core.")\S*(?:\s+\S+){0,5})/iu",$sentence,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$last_chunk=sizeof($chunks)-1;
foreach($chunks as $i=>&$chunk){  // make $chunk modifiable with & symbol
    $chunk=preg_replace("/{$pattern_core}/iu",'<b>$0</b>',$chunk,-1,$count);
    if(!$count && $chunk!=' '){  // if contains no keyword and not a single space...
        if($i==0 || $i==$last_chunk){  // single set of dots at beginning and end of sentence
            $chunk='...';
        }else{
            $chunk='... ...';  // double set of dots in the middle of sentence
        }
    }
}
echo implode($chunks);
```

Output:

```
But I must <b>explain</b> to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing <b>pleasure</b> and praising pain was born... ...I will give you a <b>complete</b> account of the system, and... ...one rejects, dislikes, or avoids <b>pleasure</b> itself, because it is <b>pleasure</b>,... ...not know how to pursue <b>pleasure</b> rationally encounter consequences that are...
```

Comment: I think this is it. I have to check on my own text

Comment: One question, if someone input "." and other there is a problem, best solution to clear this characters from string before run your script yes?

Comment: don't use this yet.  I need to fix a couple of things.  I'll ping you when I'm finished updating it. I am going to make it alright to use any character.

Comment: http://dawid969.webd.pl/text.txt - here is sentence and keywords that something goes wrong. -

Comment: unicode characters too, eh?  I need all of the details or I am wasting my time with all these rewrites.  This is why realistic input strings are essential in questions on StackOverflow.  I'll fix this up too.

Comment: ...well, I can't be too cranky, it could be worse, you could update your question in a few weeks and ask me to adjust after I've forgotten about this answer.

Comment: @dawid9692 Please confirm this is correct handling: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a91274417e59b40bbfde4c1553d2ba9fb7c82636

Comment: Ok wait let me check

Comment: It works perfectly... i cant find any bugs... Thank you. If i find smth can i write here about this?

Comment: I politely ask that I not get dragged into building this project with you, but if you have any small issues that you cannot iron out after having a try, you are welcome to leave me a comment and I'll try to help.  I will update my answer in a moment.

Comment: @dawid9692 I have made many improvements.  And now suddenly, I think I can do even better but I'd better just post this method and let you move forward.  If I can get my new idea working, I'll add it later.  (midnight here, time for bed)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$sentence = "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again";

$arrayOfWords = array('explain', 'complete', 'pleasure');

echo "<b>Sentence:</b> ".$sentence;
echo '<br><br>';

echo "<b>Words to find (in array):</b> ";
print_r($arrayOfWords);

echo "<br><br>";

//replace this part

$look = explode(' ',$sentence);
$last_checked =0;
$i=0;
$highlight=false;
for(;$i<count($look);$i++){
    foreach ($arrayOfWords as $keyword){
        $find=$look[$i];
        if(stripos($find, $keyword) !== false) {
            $highlight =true;
            if($i-$last_checked>10){
                $j = ($last_checked ==0)?0:  $last_checked+ 5;
                $dots=true;

                for(;$j<$i -5;$j++) {
                    if($dots){
                        $look[$j]= "...";
                        $dots=false;
                    }else
                        $look[$j]= "";
                }
            }
            $last_checked =$i;
        }
    }
}


$sentence=implode(" ",$look);


if(isset($highlight)){
    foreach($arrayOfWords as $key => $replace){
        $sentence = str_replace($replace,'<b>'.$replace.'</b>',$sentence);
    }
}

echo "<b>Sentence formatted I have:</b> ".$sentence;

echo '<br><br>';

echo "<b>Sentence formated I need: </b> But I must <b>explain</b> to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing <b>pleasure</b> and praising pain was born and I will give you a <b>complete</b> account of the system, and expound... ...one rejects, dislikes, or avoids <b>pleasure</b> itself, because it is pleasure,... ...not know how to pursue <b>pleasure</b> rationally encounter consequences that are...";
?>
```

I hope this gives you a view,i did't focus on exact numbers.

Comment: @M.ah Yes if you Could put all together i would be really thankful. This solution might help other people because its good solution for fiding by user keywords in text and cut text - show only important fragments. I couldnt find  finished solution for few days then i decided to write here.

Comment: i put the complete code.just there is one situation when you have a lot of words after the "last occurrence" of any of the arrayOfWords word inside text.you want to keep those words or erase all words after 5 next words?